# How do I add stuff to top bar?

Tags: application-development, gnome-shell, top-bar

This is more of a asking for direction. What are the means of developing programs that can add something to the Ubuntu top bar?

Let's say I want to make a program that shows the network traffic on the topbar. I'm focusing on GNOME. What should I learn?

p.s. I am not a newbie to programming and bash.

Comment: can you explain the objective better and/or give an example?

Comment: Lets say I want to make a program that shows the network traffic on the topbar.

Comment: It will depend on which desktop you want to program for, xfce, gnome, kde, lxde...and as far as i know, they will be extension, plugins or applets.

Comment: I'm focusing on gnome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, to add "stuff" to the top bar would require you to hack into Gnome Shell  using javascript and css. That would result in you effectively writing your own custom Gnome Shell extensions.

For what you want to achieve, you likely will be helped by the well maintained power-user [gnome shell extension argos](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos).

That extension turns the standard output of executables into panel drop-down menus. It is actually inspired and compatible with a similar tool existing in the Mac OS X world, BitBar. It takes out the heavy lifting of having to hack into gnome shell yourself, so you can focus on the tools you want to have available in your top bar. Also this eliminates the need to be confronted directly with the poorly documented and unstable Gnome Shell extensions API.

Finally, although considered "legacy" by the Gnome developers, you can work with traditional tray appindicators. To enable these on Gnome Shell, an extension is needed. Ubuntu uses the Kstatusnotifier/appindicator extension for this.

Comment: You might also mention appindicators